# How can I substitute multiple instances of a character with the same number of instances of a different character in linux sed?

Tags: grep, sed, vi

I need to substitute a repeating set of characters (2 or more) with the exact number of replacement characters. I need to do this either with sed, or within vi.

Examples

```
"abc,,,def" becomes "abc|||dev"
"1245d,,,,,22" becomes "1245d|||||22"
```

Thanks

Comment: So you need a global replacement of a character with another one, in a file?

Comment: Yes, but only where there are 2+ repetitions of it.

Comment: This can be easily achieved with `perl`: `perl -lape 's/,{2,}/"|" x length($&)/ge'`. Too bad you can't use it (why?). It *can* be called from within `vi`, don't know whether that's admissible in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe through `sed`, like

`echo "abc,,,def" | sed 's/,/|/g'`

but I would recommend to use

`tr ',' '|'`

in this case.

Comment: This would not work. As mentioned in the question, it needs to match 2 or more reps of the character.

Comment: thanks for clarification, my fault. So you want to replace only the parts in brackets: echo "a,bc,,,def" | sed -E 's/(,,+)/(\1)/g' -> a,bc(,,,)def - researching now...

Comment: partial "solution": `echo "a,b,,c,,,c" | sed 's/,,,,/||||/g; s/,,,/|||/g; s/,,/||/g' ` (expand the pattern if needed). Not really a nice solution, but *might* be of use if the maximum number of repetitions is known.

Comment: True... your approach would work if we know the max number of reps. Would be good if there is a generic solution though.

Comment: What about `echo "a,b,,c,,,c" | sed -E 's/([^,]),([^,])/\1#\2/g; s/,/|/g; s/#/,/g'`? This will convert every *single* "," to "#", then all remaining (=multiple) "," to "|", and then all saved "#" to ",". But it needs a character which is unused in the input stream (# here).

Comment: this would work. You are right in that it needs an unused character... which fortunately is available.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me for not commenting, I don't have 50 reputation.

This solution will fail if there is more patterns, like `abc,,,def,g`.

```
sed -n 's/[^,],,/&/;tsubs;p;d;:subs s/,/|/g;p' <<<'abc,,,def
abc,,def
abc,,,def,g
abc,def'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is virtually impossible, due to the way regular expressions work. As jvb already pointed out, a solution is simple (though not necessarily short) if the maximum number of consecutive source characters is known. If not,
it is possible to change all source characters first, and then change back the single characters in a second step. However, this only works if the target character does not occur in the input stream, or if you can use a character known not to occur in the input stream as an intermediate target.

Furthermore, you need to take the corner cases of a single source character occuring a the beginning or the end of the line into account. Thus:

```
tr ',' '|' < file | sed 's/\([^|]\)|\([^|]\)/\1,\2/;s/^|\([^|]\)/,\1/;s/\([^|]\)|$/\1,/'
```

or

```
sed 's/,/|/g;s/\([^|]\)|\([^|]\)/\1,\2/;s/^|\([^|]\)/,\1/;s/\([^|]\)|$/\1,/' file
```

A solution using a language that has a notion of string length would be more robust.